# How to split one excel table to several MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, automation

I am working for an organization that collects data from primary care physicians, and so we have very little input on how the data arrives here.

The physicians send us an excel sheet with ~40 columns, only about 5 of which they use for any given appointment, depending on what that particular appointment is for.

I want to normalize our database, but to avoid that creating enormous friction in uploading our data, I would have to find a way to upload from the excel file into the variously split files that are appropriate for the kind of appointment that was conducted (effectively, specified by the null columns), without requiring human oversight to sort every appointment before upload.

Is there any convenient way to do this?

Comment: Excel has a lot of that functionality built into the Data tab/ribbon

Comment: Moving forward, is there no option to approach the problem from the other end - so provide an online form through which physicians can submit this information?

Comment: You haven't provided any examples, but I would suggest you might want to consider using a stored procedure to import the raw data into a temporary table and then split the resulting records as you need them in your database.